# What does "I" represent in this context?

Tags: point-estimation

I'm trying to work on a problem which contains a symbol that I don't recall seeing before - *I*. I assume it has some special significance but I'm having a hard time looking it up. Relevant portion of the problem:

"Consider a random sample X<sub>1</sub>, ...X<sub>n</sub> from the pdf f(x; θ) = .5(1 + θx) *I*<sub>[−1,1]</sub>(x)"

If it helps, the context of the problem is point estimation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that is an indicator function. It is defined as $I_{[-1,1]}(x)=x$ if $-1\leq x\leq1$ and $0$ otherwise. I am not 100% sure since you didn't write your pdf properly.